# avfilter_graph_create_filter, error value -12

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am having some problems creating a graph filter, I keep getting an error -12 on the ret val, I am not sure why, I made sure buffersrc_ctx and filter_graph are allocated.

Where can I go to look for what error -12 is, and if anyone can tell me if they see anything that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

```
_snprintf( args, sizeof(args), 
           "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%u", 
        pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->time_base.num, 
            pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->time_base.den,
        dec_ctx->sample_rate,
        av_get_sample_fmt_name(dec_ctx->sample_fmt),
        dec_ctx->channel_layout );

ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, 
                                   buffersrc, 
                                   NULL, args, NULL, filter_graph);
```

Comment: You should post the exact error.

Comment: Essentially what is happening is the return code out of avfilter_graph_create_filter returns -12, and the function says if its less than 0 than its an error.

Comment: AVFilter *buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");  I did notice that when I call this the buffersrc is still NULL.  Is there anything wrong with this call?

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is somehow late to answer this question, but in case someone stumbles across the same problem as I have, this could help.

If the `buffersrc` is `NULL` it probably is because you forgot to register the filters with the **command**: `avfilter_register_all();`

Comment: You get error -12 returned if "AVFilter" is not registered, but it is not because of "buffersrc" is NULL. "buffersrc" is initialized in "avfilter_graph_create_filter" so it can be NULL. Anyway a down vote is too harsh since a possible solution is part of your answer.